# Unable to connect between two computers on bitorrent

Tags: networking, file-transfer, bittorrent

I'm having difficulty connecting two of my personal computers via bitorrent to transfer a large file (it's a tar file of photos, ~70gb). I have tried to transfer it over SFTP/SSH/HTTP/SFTP but keep running into the same issue: My internet connection is slow to the effect that I only get 1-2 Mbps either way when trying to directly connect, but am able to reach 10Mbps when using torrents for unrelated files. *I am looking to use bittorrent protocol largely for the capabilities provided by torrent clients (of scheduling speeds), and of interruption and resuming capabilities.*

I have two computers on different networks, that I have qbittorrent installed on both. Computer A has the file of interest, I want to transfer it to Computer B.

So far, I have tried creating a torrent file on Computer A, opening + forwarding the port used for incoming connections (57737 in my case), added multiple trackers from [this list](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ngosang/trackerslist/master/trackers_best.txt). Computer B is behind a NAT that I have not forwarded any ports. I have tried transferring the torrent file to Computer B and started running, however it doesn't seem to connect. Computer B's trackers are not as most of them 'working', however it seems to be stuck on 0%, 0 B/s upload and download.

What settings should I change to be able to connect these two computers over bittorrent protocol? Do I need to open ports on Computer B for incoming connections on that side?

Comment: Do you mean MBps or mbps? Line speeds are usually measured in megabits not megaBytes - it makes then sound faster ;) Unless you have a symmetrical connection UL speeds are usually only 10% of download speeds, so that's likely your limiting factor.

Comment: @Tetsujin, good catch. Same units, meant Megabits. I've updated the original post

Comment: Then that sounds about right - one can DL at 10mb, but the other can only UL at 1mb or so.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to be limited by your upload speed regardless of protocol.

Using bitorrent won't help unless the file is being seeded by multiple different machines with their own internet connections to upload the file to the downloading machine.

To answer the problem with resuming, just unpack the tar archive and send the files indiviually with rsync. You get your ability to resume the incomplete transfer and its much simpler.

To use qbittorrent with a private file you won't be using normal trackers.

On the hosting machine:

You need to enable qbittorrents embedded tracker option. Which you can find in the advanced options in qbitorrent.

Then you need to open the port used for the tracker.

Create the torrent with this as the tracker `http://<host IP>:<port usually 9000>/announce`

Start seeding it.

On the downloading machine:
Try to download the torrent you created.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but I am also looking for the fault tolerance/resume capabilities of torrents that just work better and are easier to deal with after a restart/log off.

Answer (score 1):

Since they're both your personal computers, I assume you have physical access. Use [*Sneakernet*](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/1880/sneakernet), which would be *much faster* than doing this online.

If there were continual changes, then this might not be as practical, but a single 70 GB file easily can be transferred to USB flash drive or external SSD or HDD, at speeds of tens to hundreds of mega**bytes** per second.

Also, use a copying mechanism that is fault-tolerant, lest the transfer be interrupted. For Windows, use built-in [Robocopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) for *robust* copying. You can also look at [ResilioConnect](https://www.resilio.com/blog/looking-for-a-robocopy-alternative) or [other alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/robocopy/).

BTW, Sneakernet has been expanded to include delivery of data on removable media by [motorcycle](https://nextbillion.net/news/internet-for-remote-places-no-literacy-required/), by [pigeon](https://spectrum.ieee.org/pigeonbased-feathernet-still-wingsdown-fastest-way-of-transferring-lots-of-data) and by [drone](https://www.businessinsider.in/facebook-secretly-explored-building-bird-sized-drones-to-ferry-data-to-people-with-bad-internet-connections/articleshow/68633354.cms).